# How can I use wp_after_insert_post with $current_screen?

Tags: posts, pages, wp-update-post

I'd like to call `add_action( 'wp_after_insert_post'` on particular screens. I'm currently checking the page like so followed by calling the `wp_after_insert_post` hook. It doesn't seem to fire but does if it's swapped with `add_action( 'current_screen', 'test' );` instead.

```
function test() {
    global $current_screen;

    if ( isset( $current_screen->base ) ) {
        if ( $current_screen->id == 'post' ) {

            $args = array(
                'ID'          => '10',
                'post_name'   => 'Some title',
            );
                        
            // Update the post
            wp_update_post( $args );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_after_insert_post', 'test', 100 );
```

Comment: The general approach is wrong because generally there is no “current screen” when a post is actually saved. You’ll need to try something else but it’s hard to make a suggestion without knowing your goals.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, the goal is to update the slug to match the title when the post is saved. If there is a similar slug, it inherits the default behavior of appending a numeral e.g. new-title-2. The thinking behind using current screen is that I would like this to happen for certain post types only including custom and native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, you don't actually care about the current screen. You care about the post type. They might be related but they're not the same thing. If you want to target a specific post type in the `wp_after_insert_post` hook, you can use the post object passed to the hook callback:

```
add_action(
    'wp_after_insert_post',
    function( $post_id, $post ) {
        if ( 'post' === get_post_type( $post ) ) {
            // Do something.
        }
    },
    10,
    2
);
```

Just replace `'post'` with whichever post type you want to check.